# Function not defined when running .mb_YTPlayer();

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a full page video background using jquery.mb.YTPlayer but I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {  
            jQuery(".player").mb_YTPlayer();   
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
    <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}">
        My video
    </a>
</body>
```

What's causing the undefined error? Is my code malformed?

Answer (score 0):

It actually had to do with the fact the order the libraries were loaded.